# How to load only selected column values via jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

When I try to pass less values from a server than there are columns on a client side, I get an alert saying it must be equal. How can I pass less values from a server? Other columns I'm planning to fill programmatically on a client side.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you fill the other columns in server-side?
Is that not an option?

Comment: Well, I can do so, of course, but the column I fill manually just contains controls such as "show info" etc. If I would pass them from the server, it would mix up my server logic.

Answer (score 0):

Right, the number of elements in your column model must exactly match the number of elements in your input data. You could work around this by just setting default values for the columns you are not planning to use. For example, just set them to null, 0, '', etc. You could even do this on the client side before you load data into your grid, if you really want to.

Comment: If the flexigrid really requires a certain number of columns from the server, I'm not sure if the client-side solution is possible. Is it? But you're right, he could set it as empty/dummy values in server-side.